# Can I localize an ASP.Net MVC 2 application to English but change the date format?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, localization, date-format

With the following tag in web.config I localized the application to english

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en" />
```

Can I change the date format to 'dd/MM/yyyy' and keep all other english culture stuff? (e.g. keep the decimal separator as dot '.').

---

**Edit**

I looking for a one-time tweak, something to setup/implement once I forget about it. I don't want to decorate all my DateTime variables used in the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. On your view model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

and in your view:

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Date) %>
```

---

UPDATE:

Another possibility is to write a custom display template (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/DateTime.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DateTime>" 
%>
<%= Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") %>
```

and then everytime you use a date in a view:

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Date) %>
```

it will use the custom display template and show the date formatted correctly. You could do the same with Editor template.

Comment: I'd clarified the question. This solution implies decorate all my DateTime variables used in the UI.

Comment: @Toto, I've updated my answer to suggest you an alternative solution using a custom display template for the `DateTime` type.